# How to pass histogram bins for each discrete value in 2D histogram and plot it

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram, visualization

My data can be seen as a time series. For `t=0` there is some data `x0`, then for `t=1` some data `x1`, etc. I am trying to create a 2D histogram using `sns.histplot` [here for reference](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) of this data. I want to bins along the y-axis to be calculated and passed separately for each `t`, but I am not sure how to do that. To provide some code:

```
time  value
0     1.2
0     1.3
0     0.4
0     0.3
0     1.34
0     1.31
0     1.36
...   ...
1     3.4
1     10.2
1     5.2
1     100.13
1     108.13
...   ...
n     1.2
n     2.5
```

I have a dataframe, `df` that looks like that. Note how a binwidth of 0.3 would be fine for `t=0` because it puts the values `0.3; 0.4` in a bin, whereas the values `1.2; 1.3; 1.34; 1.31; 1.36` in a different bin. But that binwidth for `t=1` would not work because each value would have its own bin. Instead for `t=1`, a more reasonable more binwidth would be 10, which would group `3.4; 10.2; 5.2` in a bin, and `100.13; 108.13` in a different bin. Of course, the bins don't have to have the same size, e.g., 0.3 or 10, but this is just for illustrating the issue.

Currently, the code is `sns.histplot(df, x='time', y='value', discrete=(True, False))`, but that's not what I want. I'd like to pass something like this:

```
sns.histplot(df, x='time', y='value', binwidth=(1, (binwidth_t0, binwidth_t1,...,binwidth_n)))
```

where each binwidth for each `t` is passed independently, and the same binwidth is used for x-axis (it is discrete).

Is there a way to achieve this? It also doesn't have to be with `sns.histplot`. A different library is fine. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I hope this clarifies the question. This is a plot of what I currently have: [image]
Ignore the fact there are subplots. If you look at ant, you can see the bins along the y-axis are all identical (roughly 1-2, then 2-3, etc) and they are the same for every column (every value along the x-axis). I'd like to have different bins for every `x`. I hope this makes it the question more clear. If not, please let me know.

Comment: After reading your question again, it's not clear what you want. However, a barplot seems the likeliest of options: `ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='time', y='value', estimator='mean')`. A [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) is _an approximate representation of the distribution of continuous numerical data_ for one variable: `ax = sns.histplot(df, x='value')`

Comment: I don't think a barplot would do it. In the picture added, see kitchen: there are some values that are separated from the rest. However, I'll take a look to see if I can do something with barplot.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to make a stacked bar (though that's a guess), which can be done by adding a dummy category to each value in a time group: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olEgr.png)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney a stacked bar would work, except there are (vertical) gaps (See some columns of the kitchen plot).

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be anything in the data to indicate where one bar should start and end, those values seem to just be lengths.

Comment: I'll expand my example data to make it more clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Histograms are used to show the distribution of your data points, and in your case, you clearly you have too many bins in your plots. To correct this, set the number of `bins` and change the width of the bins using `binwidth` e.g.

```
sns.histplot(df, x = 'time', y = 'value', bins = 35,  binwidth = 5)
```

Comment: It seems my question is still not clear, but this answer does not really address my question.